# Failed to create COM object `CrystalReports.ObjectFactory.2': Class not registered

Tags: php, sql-server, crystal-reports

I inherited this PHP web application that generates a PDF file from crystal reports. Now I have tried this project on a different server it seems to work properly, but when I try to view it on my development server it returns an exception:

```
Caught exception: 
Failed to create COM object `CrystalReports.ObjectFactory.2': Class not registered
```

Tracing the code and it seems that it is thrown by this:

```
$objectFactory= new COM("CrystalReports.ObjectFactory.2") or die("Unable to Create COM");
$crApp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.9") or die("Unable to Create Object");
```

I have tried installing/re-installing CR Basic Runtime on my server, but it doesn't seem to work (I'm using a 64-bit computer).

I'm using:
PHP 5.3.10, 
Crystal Reports 9, 
Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I usually receive error `"Caught exception: Failed to create COM object "Name_of_the_COM_server": Class not registered"` when COM server is not registered on the server, where WEB server is running.

You can register COM server with [Regsvr command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/regsvr32).

I suppose, that Crystal Report can be registered during installation, so you can check Crystal Report documentation.